# Using awk or sed to extract multiple information from file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a program that produces a log file which looks like this:

```
    Player: 9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1 () Item: 10/gold/tool//onehanded///, 15/gold/tool//twohanded
    Player: 8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9 () Item: 20/diamond/tool//twohanded///
    Player: 7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8 () Item: 30/copper/tool//onehanded///, 36/gold/tool//twohanded///
    Player: 6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7 () Item: 40/gold/tool//twohanded///
    Player: 5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6 () Item: 50/gold/tool//onehanded///, 55/gold/tool//twohanded///
    Player: 4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6.5 () Item: 10/gold/tool//onehanded///, 12/diamond/tool//twohanded///
    ...
```

The log file goes on and on. What I would need is output that prints all the **players** that have tools that are **gold**, along with the **ID** of that tool. For example, I would need this:

```
Player: 9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1;10;15
Player: 7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8;36
Player: 6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7;40
Player: 5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6;50;55
Player: 4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6.5;10
```

As you can see the player 8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9 is not in the output, as that player doesn't have a gold tool.

My code so far looks like this:

```
grep "/gold" file | awk -F '[()]' '{print $1}'
```

which produces this:

```
Player: 9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1
Player: 7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8
Player: 6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7
Player: 5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6
Player: 4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6.5
```

what could I add to the code above to fix it?

Comment: Incidentally, if this is *your* program, I recommend you rework it to use either a database of some sort, SQLite, or at least JSON format, so you can more easily part the data with standard tools.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -F' \\(\\) ' '
    /gold\/tool/ {
      items = $2; ids=""; 
      while(match(items,/([0-9]+)\/gold\/tool/,a)) {
        ids = ids ";" a[1]; 
        items = substr(items,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
      } 
      print $1 ids
    }' file
    Player: 9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1;10;15
    Player: 7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8;36
    Player: 6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7;40
    Player: 5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6;50;55
    Player: 4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6.5;10
```

Comment: What if I wanted to remove the tool field, so that I only scan for gold, be it items or weapons, as long as it's gold. Could I remove the /tool/ pattern from this what you've posted?

Comment: @eapoehoe yes - you should be able to simplify `/gold\/tool/` to `/gold/`, so long as it's always the string that follows the `[0-9]+/` pattern

Comment: I edited the post as I am trying to make my own solution. Now I just need to add the ";" and IDs. Know how to add to the existing code I made?

Comment: @eapoehoe the above answer shows how to add the `;` and IDs - you loop over the string, regex matching them until you can't find any more

Answer (score 1):

Inspired  by  steeldriver, perhaps a little simpler:

```
gawk '{
    g=0
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (match($i, /^([0-9]+)\/gold/, a)) {
            if (g++ == 0) printf "%s %s", $1, $2
            printf ";%s", a[1]
        }
    }
    if (g > 0) printf "\n"
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed in extended regexp mode `-E` to make the regex writing less daunting. The approach used is to immediately discard any noninteresting lines, viz., those that don't comprise gold. After that we strip off all non gold medals while peeling away just the digits before the gold medal:

```
$ sed -Ee '
   s/\s*[(][)]\s*/\n/
   \|\n.*[0-9]/gold/|!d
    :a
    /\n$/!{
      \|\n([0-9]+)/gold/\S+\s*|{
      s//;\1\n/;ba
    }
    s|\n\S+\s*|\n|;ba
  }
  s/(^\s*|\s*$)//g
' file.log
```

Perl makes the task trivial:

```
$ perl -F'[(][)]' -lane '
   (my $p = $F[0]) =~ s/(^\s*|\s*$)//g;
   my @A = $F[1] =~ m[\D(\d+)/gold/]g;
   print join ";", $p, @A if @A;
' file.log
```

**Results:**

```
Player: 9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.1;10;15
Player: 7.6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8;36
Player: 6.5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7;40
Player: 5.4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6;50;55
Player: 4.3.2.1.9.8.7.6.5;10
```